# Ruby on Rails - Postgres: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, sqlite

For my Rails app im switching from sqlite3 to Postgres for the production environment. I want to take the data from the sqlite db to the postgres db.

I set up postgres and the superuser.

When I user `rake db:setup` all goes well up to the part where it is supposed to seed the db.

This error appears:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "---
- ''
"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

My database contains arrays and this worked fine on sqlite, even when migrating and seeding to a new setup.

I guess the error is caused by the syntax not being compatible with a postgres db. Can i create a seeds.rb file that contains the right syntax if that is the case?

Any help is appreciated.

Versions:

```
Rails 4.1.8
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like the array is being serialized to YAML before being inserted into the database (`---` indicates the start of a YAML document).

I'm guessing your model has e.g. `serialize :some_field, Array`, which would be necessary to store an array in SQLite, but will cause a problem if you're now using a native Postgres array column type. If you have a line like that in your model, try removing it.

Comment: Downvoter: Please leave a comment explaining the reason for your downvote. If my answer is wanting I would be happy to try and improve it.

Comment: This helped me out a lot, thanks Jordan! I hope this makes up for whoever downvoted your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Jordan's answer is absolutely correct, but in my case I ended up adding a migration to store the array in YAML format.

```
change_column :table, :column, :text, default: [].to_yaml
```